# How would I validate string length using DataAnnotations in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex, validation, data-annotations

I am using DataAnnotations in an ASP.NET MVC 1 application to check for Required fields and numerical ranges using the Required and Range attributes.

I am looking for the best way to validate the length of strings in a few input text boxes. I see that there is a RegularExpression attribute that could do the job but I was wondering if there was a more specific attribute to do this?

Also if anyone can point me to a decent resource regarding using DataAnnotations I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about [the StringLength attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx)?

Comment: @Anders - [StringLength] isn't specific to MVC, right?  The documentation doesn't suggest so, but I'm using it in a straight console app and it isn't firing on a rule violation.  All examples I Google reference MVC.

Comment: @Howiecamp The attribute in itself is "just a class" and can be used wherever you like. It's up to the application to actually do anything with it though. ASP.NET MVC looks for the data annotation attributes by default; if you want to use them in another context that hasn't got this built in you will have to add the functionality yourself. I think you could apply [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3783328/121146) to your problem.