# How can I use the Data Validation Attributes in C# in a non-ASP.net context?

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I'd like to use the data validation attributes in a library assembly, so that any consumer of the data can validate it without using a ModelBinder (in a console application, for instance). How can I do it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Actually this is pretty cool. I used it in a WFP validation implementation recently. Most people end up writing lots of code using reflection to iterate the attributes, but there's a built in function for this.

```
var vc = new ValidationContext(myObject, null, null);
return Validator.TryValidateObject(myObject, vc, null, true);
```

You can also validate attributes on a single named property. You can also optionally pass in a list in order to access the error messages :

```
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
var vc = new ValidationContext(myObject, null, null) { MemberName = "UserName"};
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, vc, results);

// get all the errors
var errors = Array.ConvertAll(results.ToArray(), o => o.ErrorMessage);
```

Comment: I ended up writing a lot of reflection code to do this while I waited on an answer :(

Comment: Yeah surprisingly few examples around using this API, and loads using reflection!

Comment: not a huge fan of output parameters, so I raised a custom exception instead (impossible to ignore)

Comment: @TheCodeKing: most likely because there's loads of old examples for .NET 3.5 or older, where the number of validator attribute classes is really small and there's no ValidationContext nor Validation class.

Comment: When initializing the VaildationContext why is it required to also specify the MemberName property? I found I kept getting ArgumentNullException when not specifying it.

Comment: This is fantastic! For those interested, I use that in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/JimmyBoh/b7c135820c18a06648a5) as a simple helper class.

Comment: Very Handy.  I just added a few lines to my Business Object base class and I can use across all of my BO.  Thanks Much!

Comment: So i finally implemented this the right way this morning, 5 years after asking. Thanks man

Comment: What about nested objects / lists of objects / etc? This solution is non-recursive, but I think to be fully robust, it would need to be recursive. Anything built-in for that, or would you have to roll that manually?

Comment: @gzak For nested items I built my own ValidateObjectAttribute that inherits from ValidationAttribute. See this gist https://gist.github.com/odyth/905bcaa84d257f663eb45a55481b660b

Answer (score 2):

The `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute` classes have `IsValid` methods that perform the validation logic. They take an Object (the value of the field they decorate) and return `true` or `false`.

You can use these attributes, and a little reflection, to roll your own aspect-oriented validator. Pass your validator an object, and the validator will get a list of `PropertyInfo`s and `FieldInfo`s. For each of these, it can call `GetCustomAttributes` to look for those that inherit from `ValidationAttribute`, and for each of these, call `IsValid`, passing the value of the property or field. This can be done totally dynamically without knowing the structure of the class to be validated at design-time.

Comment: Can I call the `TryValidateProperty` passing a random instance of `ValidationAttribute` to perform on?

Answer (score 0):

`TryValidateProperty` is just badly written - you have to jump through hoops to get it to work outside a Controller, and even then, if you use it twice, it will end up quietly setting ModelState to valid/invalid and stop alterring that state, and stop returning accurate results from then on.

I gave up on it and just wrote my own validator. This'll loop over any set of objects in any context and tell you if they're valid:

```
bool isValid = true;
var invalidFields = new List<string>();

foreach (var o in viewModels)
{
    var properties = o.GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach(var prop in properties)
    {
        var attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        if (attrs != null)
        {
            var val = prop.GetValue(o);
            ValidationAttribute[] validatorAttrs = attrs
                .Where(a => a is ValidationAttribute)
                .Select(a => (ValidationAttribute)a).ToArray();

            foreach(var attr in validatorAttrs)
            {                       
                bool thisFieldIsValid = attr.IsValid(val);
                if (!thisFieldIsValid)
                    invalidFields.Add(prop.Name);

                isValid = isValid && thisFieldIsValid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```